# HTML in PHP wont load images or certain parts of my CSS

Tags: php, html, css, image

I am trying to connect my website to a MySQL database so I started using PHP and thought that I could keep all of my HTML and CSS the same but when I added everything, the website's images don't show up as they did before but fonts and other stuff are the same, please help.

[index.php - images wont load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8ZXG.png)

[Homestyle.css - Background image wont load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEg76.png)

Comment: Never post images of code. Post your code. We need a [mcve]

Comment: As per [ask] please provide all code and data as text. You can [edit] your question. Thanks

Comment: Anyway it likely won't load the images because the values you supplied are filesystem paths, not URLs...do you understand the difference? Websites require URLs since they use HTTP to fetch data, not file paths

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to include path of your css file to your page. It is wrong. If you want to connect your external css file with your html page then use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="url/to/your/styleheet.css">` and put it inside `<head>` tag.